# Using a file to install packages with apt-get

Tags: apt, software-installation

I find it very convenient to install packages on a new machine through package files like brewfiles, caskfiles, dockerfiles, package.json etc.

Is there an alternative to this for apt-get since I still just use it
through commandline with

```
apt-get install pkg1 pkg2 pkg3…
```

?

Comment: Does it need one? You could use [`xargs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/xargs.1): `xargs -P1 apt-get install < list-of-packages`.

Comment: @muru well I don't really know how xargs works (reading man now) but I don't think that is a solution to having the packages centralised in one file? I would still have to manually list the files after the < since using a .txt file with three packages in it doesn't work with this command (tested on Debian)

Comment: the `<` is shell redirection. For multiple files, use: `cat file1 file2 ..  | xargs -P1 apt-get install`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As specified in the comments of your question, you can write a simple text file, listing the packages to install:

```
iceweasel
terminator
vim
```

Assuming this is stored in `packages.txt`, then run the following command:

```
xargs sudo apt-get -y install < packages.txt
```

`xargs` is used to pass the package names from the `packages.txt` file to the command line. From the `xargs` manual:

> `xargs` reads
> items
> from  the  standard  input, delimited by blanks (which can be protected
> with double or single quotes or a backslash) or newlines, and  executes
> the  command (default is `/bin/echo`) one or more times with any initial
> arguments followed by items read from standard input.

Answer (score 34):

Improving a bit on the answer of @ortomala-lokni, you can give the file directly as an argument to `xargs`:

```
xargs -a packages.txt sudo apt-get install
```

Optionally you can give `xargs` the `-r` option to prevent the `apt-get` call from being run at all if your `packages.txt` does not contain any non-whitespace characters.

Comment: This may be a peculiarity of Alpine / BusyBox, but the `-a` arg wasn't documented and didn't seem to work there: `xargs: unrecognized option: a`.  My version output shown is `BusyBox v1.27.2 (2017-12-12 10:41:50 GMT) multi-call binary.`

Comment: @TaylorD.Edmiston BusyBox really isn't completely compatible with coreutils...

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt install `cat somefile`
```

Just replace *`somefile`* with the name of the file with path, if necessary. 
Note that this command uses backquotes. 
A backquote will execute the contents and then include the results in the line.

Comment: Please don't use backticks.  They're rarely the best solution to a problem.  I'd suggest `sudo apt install $(cat somefile)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the more general scripting solutions, you can create a deb package.

you will need

- `equivs-build`, to build the deb. The deb can only contain dependencies. This is a simplified deb builder.
- `gdebi` to install the deb.

This will work on all debian based systems (systems that use apt/deb-files).

The advantage of doing it with deb files, as opposed to a shell script, is that it is much easier to undo, you can uninstall a deb, or re-configure a deb, and re-install it (this will cause files to be added and removed).

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread has been quite awhile, but recently I just wrote a tool, [`sysdep`](https://github.com/Benjamin-Tan/sysdep), just for this exact purpose. It is a simple tool that reads from a `toml` file instead of a plain text file. Suggestion and feedback are welcome!

1. Download with

   ```shell
   curl -L https://github.com/Benjamin-Tan/sysdep/releases/latest/download/sysdep-$(arch)-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.gz | tar -xz -C ~/.local/bin
   ```
2. Create a `system_dependencies.toml`

   ```
   [dependencies]
   apt = ["libpackage", "libpackage2"]
   ```
3. `sysdep list` to list the dependencies, should display 'libpackage', 'libpackage2'.
4. `sysdep install` to install them
5. `sysdep` to display the help page for more options.