# How do I comment out package names kept in a text file for mass installing?

Tags: apt, software-installation

I am mass installing apt-get packages from a "packages.txt" (or call it what you like) as explained at [Using a file to install packages with apt-get](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179851/using-a-file-to-install-packages-with-apt-get).

Commenting out "terminator" apt package:

```
iceweasel
#terminator
vim
```

throws an error:

`The command '/bin/sh -c xargs -a /tmp/packages.txt apt-get install -y' returned a non-zero code: 123`

In contrast, if you fill a "requirements.txt" for a Python instead like here in a Dockerfile, it ignores each line starting with `#`.

```
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r /tmp/requirements.txt
```

with "requirements.txt":

```bsh
python3-pip
mysql-client
#mysql-server
libmysqlclient-dev
python3-dotenv
```

Result: `mysql-server` is skipped.

How would I comment out an apt package in a "packages.txt"?

Answer (score 2):

Filter the list of packages before feeding it to `xargs`:

```
grep -v '^#' /tmp/packages.txt | xargs -r sudo apt-get install -y
```

Adding `-r` to the `xargs` invocation ensures that nothing happens if all lines in `packages.txt` are commented out.